What's the yaml file to get a report from the tests on the azure DevOps pipeline for a native iOS app project
I have an Azure DevOps pipeline to build test and archive a native iOS app, but I cannot see the test results or the code coverage report.
The PublishTestResults@2 has the following test Results Formats:

JUnit
NUnit
VSTest
XUnit
CTest

But none of them are used from Xcode XCTests.
Is there a way to see the test results or the code coverage report? If yes, please show me the yaml file.
I have already tried on the yaml file:
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
   testResultsFormat: JUnit
   testResultsFiles: '**/*.xml'
   searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results/'

But it doesn't work for Xcode XCTests.

Your best option is probably to convert the test results to one of the supported formats, for example JUnit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524687/convert-xcode-11-testresult-xcresult-to-junit and https://docs.testmo.com/integrations/automation/xctest

Test results
In Xcode@5 - Xcode v5 task, there is an option publishJUnitResults used to publish JUnit test results to the Azure Pipelines. It uses xcpretty to format xcodebuild output.
- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'test'
    configuration: '$(Configuration)'
    sdk: '$(SDK)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(path)'
    scheme: '$(Scheme)'
    xcodeVersion: '13'
    packageApp: false
    signingOption: 'auto'
    useXcpretty: true
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testRunTitle: 'iOS Tests'

Code Coverage
To publish the Code Coverage reports generated by XCode to the Azure Pipeline, you can use the Slather third party tool.
To use this tool, install it first using the gem install slather script. Then publish the code coverage report using the PublishCodeCoverageResults task.
- script: gem install slather
  displayName: 'Install Slather'
- script: slather coverage -x --scheme $(scheme) --workspace $(workspacePath) --output-directory $(coveragePath) $(projectPath)
  displayName: 'Run slather to convert Code Coverage'
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@2
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: '$(coveragePath)/cobertura.xml'


See the details from this blog.
